# Rook error: unused arguments

Tags: r, r-rook-package

```
> library(Rook)
> s <- Rhttpd$new()
> s$add(name='MyApp',plot_ind_brz='D:/STOCK/plot_ind_brz.R')
```

I am getting an error

```
"Error in s$add(name = "MyApp", plot_ind_brz = "D:/STOCK/plot_ind_brz.R") : 
  unused argument(s) (plot_ind_brz = "D:/STOCK/plot_ind_brz.R")"
```

And steps are written as follows:

Load Rook

> ```
> library(Rook)
> ```

Create an Rhttpd variable

> ```
> s <- Rhttpd$new()
> ```

Create your application in a separate file, assign it to either the
name of your application or simply just 'app'.

Add your application to the server:

> ```
> s$add(name='MyApp',app='path/to/your/app.R')
> ```

Load the app into your browser

> ```
> s$browse('MyApp')"
> ```

How to resolve this problem? Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the instructions, `app` is the name of a formal parameter to the `add()` function. Even if your app is named differently, this has to remain unchanged:

```
s$add(name='MyApp', app='D:/STOCK/plot_ind_brz.R')
```

Comment: "Error in .Object$initialize(...) : 
  Cannot find a suitable app in file D:/STOCK/plot_ind_brz.R" Can't we run normal r files here?

Comment: @user2969490: Please open a new question.